# PDFBox not writing lines correctly in new PDDocument

Tags: java, pdf, text, pdfbox

I have a long text (which I got by using PDFTextStripper) I splitted in lines by doing `text.split("\\r\\n");`,

Then I remove control characters:

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
line = line.replaceAll("\\r", "");
line = line.replaceAll("\\n", "");
```

Now I declare the content stream and I set the font (newDoc and newPage are PDDocument and PDPage):

```
    PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(newDoc, newPage);
    cs.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12);
```

After that, I write the text on the page. According to how the line starts (if the line starts with "1." I want to write it with the COS tag H1, and if it starts with something else I want to write it as normal text):

```
        for (String line : lines) {
           
            if (line.startsWith("1.")) {
                COSName tag = COSName.getPDFName("H1");
                cs.beginText();
                cs.newLineAtOffset(50, 700);  
                cs.beginMarkedContent(tag);                  
                cs.showText(line);
            } else {
                cs.beginText();
                cs.newLineAtOffset(50, 700);
               
                cs.showText(line);
            }
            cs.endText();
            cs.endMarkedContent();
        }
        cs.close();
    }
```

Then I save the doc. and close it:

```
newDoc.save("marked.pdf");
newDoc.close();
```

The problem is, when I run my program, the result PDF (marked.pdf) shows one line per page, and it should be showing all the lines of the first page on the first page and so on.
This is how it looks:
[PDF Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLX9P.png)

Another problem, is that the line should be ending when the page ends, but all the lines continue even if the page width ended. All the code above (except the splitting of the text and cleaning of the lines) is running inside a loop which repeats one time per page of the original document. If someone could give me some insights about working with this, I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"All the code above (except the splitting of the text and cleaning of the lines) is running inside a loop which repeats one time per page of the original document."* - Most likely this code frame (which you don't show) is buggy. Furthermore, you draw all text in the line starting at 50, 700. This most likely is not what you want.  Also you have too many `endMarkedContent` calls.

Comment: By the way, are you sure you should split at `"\\r\\n"` instead of at `"\\n"`? Have you checked whether your `lines` look like you think they do?

Comment: @mkl I tried printing in screen the lines and they are correct but it's only showing the lines of the first page